# Can't reset form with '$setPristine'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I get an error when I run the following code to reset my form:

```
 $scope.saveFormData = function () {
            $scope.testForm.$setPristine();
}
```

And HTML:

```
<form name="testForm" >

                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                    <span class="input-label">Title</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="formData.shortDesc" required="">
                </label>
 <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" ng-click="saveFormData()" >Opslaan </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the error message that you're getting.

Comment: Here it is: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Comment: The error is saying it can't find the Angular `FormController` that should be on the scope under the property name `testForm`. One way for this to happen is by using a directive that creates another scope like (ng-if, ng-include, etc.).  If you still need to resolve the error, you might show us more of the HTML (starting from where the controller is specified down to the form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/rejfph9s/3/), try to add the condition if the form exists, but I don't know what error you get:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.saveFormData = function() {
        if ($scope.testForm) {
           $scope.testForm.$setPristine();
           $scope.formData = {};
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My goal is to clear the text field. Or am I using the wrong function?

Comment: @EdzoBlaauw you are using the wrong function :) `$setPristine()` resets form validation errors and whether the form is "dirty" or not. To clear the text field, you should set the model to the empty string or null.

Comment: Also You can place your saveFormData()  function call  on form.

It will do form submission and clicking action at the same time.            <form name="testForm" ng-submit="saveFormData()">

Comment: Thank you guys @Sunil and @Riyaj!! Learned something today :))

Comment: Just updated post and fiddle to reset the formData too